# Receive Drive content notifications in an Android app without a backend

Tags: android, push-notification, google-drive-api

I have to use Google Drive REST API due to the limitation of Android Drive API for my android app. Everything works properly until registering for change notification. From the [API docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/push), the workflow is:

- Register a domain such as `example.com` with Google Cloud Console
- When a change happens, Drive API will send a post to `https://example.com/notifications`

Is it possible to receive push notification from Google Drive on an android app without my own backend server?

Comment: you'll need an http server running on your phone. There is code on Github that will allow you to embed the server in your app. Dynamic DNS will handle the routing. However, a simple backend to convert the notifications to Firebase Cloud Messaging would probably be simpler.

Comment: @pinoyyid thanks for the solution, but if so, my app only receives notification when running that is not practical

Comment: Well you could run it as a Service, but nevertheless I agree which is why I steered you towards a simple FCM server.

Answer (score 1):

you'd have define that [push notification](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/push) URL as a Cloud Function [HTTP Trigger](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/http)'s URL - which then pushes a [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) notification to an Android client, whenever it is being triggered.
basically, this would be a HTTP push notification sending out a subsequent FCM push notification.

Comment: sound complicated, do you have kind of tutorial for this, I am not familiar with backend stuff

Comment: @thanhbinh84 have linked some of the documentation, while it obviously would need that one Cloud Function scripted. the GSuite Admin SDK is not even useful here, because one can only pull this information; updated my answer to the least required.

Comment: @thanhbinh84 here would be one relevant tutorial: https://android.jlelse.eu/serverless-notifications-with-cloud-functions-for-firebase-685d7c327cd4 while for Drive, one needs an HTTP trigger,  instead of changes to a Firebase database, in order to know when to run the cloud function.